# Suppress PostCSS warnings from imported dependency's stylesheets

Tags: javascript, eslint, froala

Some dependencies require you to import CSS from node_modules into your file.

```
// editor.js
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css';
import FroalaEditor from 'react-froala-wysiwyg';

export default = () => <FroalaEditor />
```

The package's CSS file in this case can cause errors.

```
Compiled with warnings.

./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css)

Warning
(1990:3) Replace fill-available to stretch, because spec had been changed

./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css)

Warning
(2047:3) Replace fill-available to stretch, because spec had been changed

./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css)

Warning
(2111:3) Replace fill-available to stretch, because spec had been changed
```

eslint disable lint warnings from node_modules, except, seemingly, when you import the file. How could you suppress these warnings?

What I've tried:

- Adding filename .eslintignore
- // eslint-disable-next-line before import in editor.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning generated by PostCSS. Specifically, it is being emitted by Autoprefixer. (This is a valid warning and stretch will auto-prefix to `fill-available`) To suppress the error, **you should disable PostCSS/Autoprefixer from running on external CSS that you have imported**. The method to do so is dependent on the specific build toolchain being used.